issue when sprintf with same variable with format update
int main(void) {
    char* data = calloc(250, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(data, "Hello World");
    sprintf(data, "Test %s data", data);
    printf("String:- %s \n", data);
    return 0;
}


Test Hello World data

Note:- don't add extra char array variable.

Possibly undefined behaviour, overwriting the source (as with memcpy()).

Is sprintf(buffer, "%s […]", buffer, […]) safe? Spoiler: No

From this sprintf (etc.) reference: "The C standard and POSIX specify that the behavior of sprintf and its variants is undefined when an argument overlaps with the destination buffer."

@WeatherVane  how to copy with specific %s index?

Fortunately the workaround for your shown case is simple: Just use one single sprintf call (though I would recommend using snprintf instead) to create the whole string, without strcpy.

If you want to do this strictly in-place, then it looks like you can't use sprintf.  Instead, you'd need to move the string within the array (from back-to-front), or alternatively use some overlap-save memory copy function. Then add the additional text once the string has been relocated.  But it seems like more trouble than it's worth.  It's easier to simply use a different buffer.

If you wanted to do it in-place, you could use a memmove to move the original contents to the correct position, then use two memcpy to add the prefix and suffix.

Your code has undefined behavior due to an overlap between part of the source and the destination.  This is spelled out in section 7.21.6.6p2 of the C standard regarding the sprintf function:

The sprintf function is equivalent to fprintf, except that the output
is written into an array (specified by the argument s) rather than to
a stream. A null character is written at the end of the characters
written; it is not counted as part of the returned value. If copying
takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined

The best way to handle this is to write to a second buffer to accomplish what you want.
If you must use a single buffer, you'll need to use memmove which allows overlapping to shift the original string, then use memcpy to insert the prepended part and strcat for the appended part.
strcpy(data, "Hello World");
memmove(data + strlen("Test "), data, strlen(data) + 1);
memcpy(data, "Test ", strlen("Test "));
strcat(data, " data");

